# JSP and Restlets

Tags: restlet

I developed a simple web servie using restlets . everything s fine i can call a URI and connect to db and do modifications , but when i tried to do the same using jsp s i was not able to get the jsp page itself in the browser . How can i connect a jsp page to this restlet ?

Comment: are you using the restlet standalone server?...what server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

See this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275904/configure-restlet-to-return-jsps-on-google-app-engine) and the answer from Rich Seller. I personally prefer using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net)